# Where can I ask for the location of a particular development software item?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know that Stack Exchange is not the right place to post questions looking for general software, but my question is very specific. Where do I post when I'm looking for a specific programming tool?

I'm looking for a downloadable copy of the javadoc.jar for [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8)'s "Compiler Tree API". It does not seem to be included in the [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit). The online version is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/, but I cannot integrate that into my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think your best bet would be to ask about this in chat.

The problem with your question is that it pretty much requires an answer that's a link to somewhere else.

We *really* prefer answers to be self-contained and not require linking because links age and die and that would make any answers you got of zero value after that happens. So, I don't think that your question would be on topic on any site here.

Chat is different. You can ask for help finding this stuff there. It sort of requires that you be willing to interact with people a bit but if you find the right room, you'll likely find some helpful people.

Alternately, (please forgive me if I'm confused) but you could probably ask your actual question on Stack Overflow:

> Java 8's "Compiler Tree API" does not seem to be included in the JDK. The online version is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/) but I cannot integrate that into my IDE. How can I implement this if I don't have the javadoc.jar? [Insert explanation of your IDE/project stuff.]

Answers may not require it if you're missing some part of the process.

Comment: His question is **already answered** on [so] ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could ask this question on https://stackoverflow.com.

However, if you did, your question would probably be closed as a duplicate of [Java Compiler Tree API - How do I set it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484644/java-compiler-tree-api-how-do-i-set-it-up):

> I wish to use the Java Compiler Tree in Eclipse. I have come across the API itself on the oracle web site here, however I cannot find the jar file for the library. Am I missing something?!

Which has the following answer:

> ```
> com.sun.source.tree.*
> com.sun.source.util.*
> ```
>
> Above packages can be found in tools.jar. Please add tools.jar to
>   classpath. You can find tools.jar in /lib folder. Also, you can
>   extract src.zip and find the related api source files there.